# Erlang: search string in an tuple without converting into lists and string tokens

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I have a tuple as {'Europe-Fiat-Italy-Warehouse'}.
Car = {'Europe-Fiat-Italy-Warehouse'}.

I want to search the string "Fiat" in the above tuple without converting them to string tokens in a list.
i.e.,

```
(madmax@erlang)46>string:tokens(atom_to_list(element(1, Car)), "-").
["Europe","Fiat","Italy","Warehouse"]
(madmax@erlang)46> ["Europe", "Fiat" | Other] = 
string:tokens(atom_to_list(element(1, Car)), "-").
["Europe","Fiat","Italy","Warehouse"]
(madmax@erlang)47>
(madmax@erlang)47> Other.
["Italy","Warehouse"]
(madmax@erlang)48>
```

As in above, we convert tuple to atom, then atom to list and then list to string tokens.  Is there any optimized way? or any Buit-in-Function available in erlang which make this task easier?

Comment: An aside: you know that tuples are a "scarce" resource, right? By having (combinatoric) tuples like this, you might be in danger of running out of tuple space. Consider a different representation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `string:str`

check documentation here: http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#str-2

it will return position of substring, zero if substring is not found.

```
string:str(atom_to_list(element(1, Car)), "Fiat")
```

Answer (score 0):

the representation of atoms in memory is not using strings (or list), to search in an atom name there is no other choice than convert it into list first. It is possible to use library function such as string:str/2, but you may have bad results since string you search could be part of a longer one, so you should keep the call to string:token/2, then it depends of what you want to do:

```
1> Car = {'Europe-Fiat-Italy-Warehouse'}.
{'Europe-Fiat-Italy-Warehouse'}
2> Words = string:tokens(atom_to_list(element(1, Car)), "-").
["Europe","Fiat","Italy","Warehouse"]
3> lists:member("Fiat",Words). % only a test
true
4> lists:dropwhile(fun(X) -> "Fiat" =/= X end ,Words). % words after
["Fiat","Italy","Warehouse"]
5> lists:takewhile(fun(X) -> "Fiat" =/= X end ,Words). % words before
["Europe"]
6>  lists:member("Fit",Words). % same thing with a bad match
false
7> lists:dropwhile(fun(X) -> "Fit" =/= X end ,Words). 
[]
8> lists:takewhile(fun(X) -> "Fit" =/= X end ,Words). 
["Europe","Fiat","Italy","Warehouse"]
9>
```